# Optimized solution for pagination

Tags: database, pagination

I'm making a pagination for a very large database. So it is important to use best query. Now I need to know what is the fastest way to know mysql rows number?
which one is the best and why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Limit in MySQL: http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/UseLIMITinSELECT.htm

It's the best because is the only way to do "pagination" on the database side.

Answer (score 0):

```
$perPage = 20;
$page = x;

$content = get_page(x);

function get_page($p)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `content` LIMIT ".($p-1)*$perPage.",".$perPage;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total number of rows that will be returned by your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your query here;
```

Then to paginate your query with OFFSET(first row to start at) and LIMIT(maximum number of rows to return):

```
SELECT your query LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've collected a number of pagination plugins available in the web. It comes with a great user interactivity which enhances the user experience. They all use jquery and AJAX to implement the feature.
http://itswadesh.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/11-jquery-pagination-plugins-you-must-try/